# How to use JDialog to get input

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Within SpaceInvadersApp.gameEnded() (show below), how can I use JOptionPane.showInputDialog()
to display a dialog following the initial Game Over message dialog to users
who have won the game with a score greater than zero (isGameWon method tests this). The new dialog should inform the user that they have achieved a high score and request their name for the high score table.

```
 public void gameEnded() {
    String message;
    if (game.isGameWon()) {
        message = "You defeated the alien menace!  Congratulations!\n\n"
                + "Your score was " + game.getScore();
    } else {
        message = "Oh no! The aliens have defeated you.";
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
            message, "Game Over",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    menuItemGamePause.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: You seem to have the answer in your first sentence. Your code uses `showMessage`, not `showInput`. The latter returns  String

Comment: I know JOptionPane.showInputDialog() but could someone show me how to get input such as a name in popup that pops after the popup above?

Comment: @peeskillet I would like an additional popup asking for the name to popup after the popup in the code above.

Comment: [The Java Tutorials - How to make Dialogs - Getting the user's input from a dialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

But basically, you could do something like...

```
if (game.isGameWon()) {
    message = "You defeated the alien menace!  Congratulations!\n\n"
            + "Your score was " + game.getScore();
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, message, "Game Over", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE)
    if (name != null) {
        // Save name
    }
} else {
    message = "Oh no! The aliens have defeated you.";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
            message, "Game Over",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. but what do you mean by  JOption in the secondline?

Comment: What does the error field Component.Name is not visible mean? I dont see any name variable?